# minimal javascript library to add css3 selectors to internet explorer using jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I know already about [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and [ie-css3.js](http://www.keithclark.co.uk/labs/ie-css3/), but since I have jQuery in all of my pages already, I was looking for something that uses its built-in selector parser to add this functionality only.

I just need to be able to use selectors in my css such as `.class1 + .class2, span ~ img, img[alt^=This]` ecc and have them parsed with jQuery/applied in IE6+, thanks to some tiny addon that I couldn't google. Possible?

Comment: Do you want to enable these selectors for use *within* jQuery itself, or use jQuery to get IE to understand/apply these selectors used in your stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).